# Can't update db using c# loop

Tags: loops, sql-update

Im trying to update rows in my table using loop, I get no error but nothing changed in my data...Thats my code.. What am I missing ?

```
  private void updateZipInDB(List<ZipObj> zipCodeToUpdate)
        {
            var comm = "";
            string DbConnString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConnectionString"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnString))
            {

                comm = "UPDATE Account SET address1_postalcode = @newVal WHERE AccountId = @accountID";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comm, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newVal", "f");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID", "f");
                    for (int i = 0; i < zipCodeToUpdate.Count; i++)
                    {
                       zipCodeToUpdate[i].NewVal + "' WHERE AccountId = '" + zipCodeToUpdate[i].AccountId + "'";
                        command.Parameters["@newVal"].Value = zipCodeToUpdate[i].NewVal;
                        command.Parameters["@accountID"].Value = zipCodeToUpdate[i].AccountId;

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                     conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to confirm that the variables contain what you think they do?

Comment: Yes the vars contains the right data.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? (please update tags). You can use SQL Profiler to capture the actual query being submitted and see what's going on. There's probably a data type issue.. trailing spaces, hidden chars, either in your update or in the SQL you're running to test it